# PlantUML: Package order / layout

Tags: layout, architecture, plantuml

I would like to arrange the packages top to bottom

Like:

V

IV

III

II

I

instead of the mix, see the attached picture. Is it somehow possible that all packages have the same width?

Or is there a better way to make a diagram like that in PlantUML?

Thanks!

```
@startuml Arch

skinparam componentStyle uml2
'top to bottom direction
left to right direction

package Group {            
    package "V" {       
        component "V_A"
        component "V_B"
    }
    
    package "IV" {
            component "IV_A"
            component "IV_B"
            component "IV_C"        
    }

    package "III" {
        component "III_A"
        component "III_B"
        component "III_C"        
        
    }
    
    package "II" {
        component "II_A"
        component "II_B"
        component "II_C"        
    }

    package "I" {        
        component "I_A" 
        component "I_B"
    }
}
@enduml
```

[image: Example]

After some more reading, I found a way to order the packages top to bottom, next issue: is it possible to use similar width for all packages?

```
@startuml Arch

skinparam componentStyle uml2


package Group {            
    package "V" {       
        component "V_A"
        component "V_B"
    }    
    package "IV" {
            component "IV_A"
            component "IV_B"
            component "IV_C"        
    }

    package "III" {
        component "III_A"
        component "III_B"
        component "III_C"        
        
    }

    package "II" {
        component "II_A"
        component "II_B"
        component "II_C"        
    }

    package "I" {        
        component "I_A" 
        component "I_B"
    }    
    I --[hidden]up-- II
    II --[hidden]up-- III
    III --[hidden]up-- IV
    IV --[hidden]up-- V
}
@enduml
```

[image: Second try]